# How do I create an object for Hibernate's query response?

Tags: java, hibernate

Using an object that extends HibernateDaoSupport, I ran a query using this right here:

```
List<Object> trialList2 = getSession().createSQLQuery(trialQuery2).list();
```

Where trialQuery2 is just some query that returned a single row. I got back a list with one Object on it, which when inspected in Eclipse looks like this:

```
[some, random, data]
```

I'd like to create an Object that can accommodate what I got back from the query, but a simple Javabean object that can has those fields doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what kind of object I would have to make to be able to access those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be actually `Object[]` not `Object`

```
List<Object[]> trialList2
```

Based on columns in your select query, you get values from index

Let us say, if your query is `select firstname, lastname from employee;`

`Object[0]` would be firstname

`Object[1]` would be lastname.

As per [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) :

> These will return a List of Object arrays (Object[]) with scalar values for each column in the table

Answer (score 0):

U can replace any class name for BEANCLASSNAME

```
List<BEANCLASSNAME> trialList2 = getSession().createSQLQuery(trialQuery2).setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(BEANCLASSNAME.class)).list();
```